Blazor Base Class Parameter not binding to TextEdit
I have a Base class for an Add/Edit form
public partial class BaseAddForm<TInput, TOutput> : ComponentBase
    where TInput : BaseModel, new()
    where TOutput: BaseModel, new()

In this base I have the [Parameter]
    [Parameter]
    public TInput Input { get; set; }

In the drived class (which is using Blazorise compoents) I then bind as follows;
        <Validation Validator="@ValidationRule.None">
            <Field Horizontal="true" ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6.OnDesktop">
                <FieldLabel ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is3.OnDesktop">Group</FieldLabel>
                <FieldBody ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is9.OnDesktop">
                    <TextEdit @ref="companyGroupTextBox" @bind-Text="@Input.Group" Placeholder="Enter the Company Group Name..">
                    </TextEdit>
                </FieldBody>
            </Field>

However, the field is appearring as blank when rendering (even though Input has values).
In the derived class .cs OnInitializedAsync() I have (redcued for brevity);
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Test = Input;

        if (Input.Address == null)
        {
            Input.Address = new CompanyAddressInputModel();
        }

        if (Input.Contacts != null)
        {
            var primaryContact = Input.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsPrimaryContact);

            if (primaryContact != null)
            {
                InputMainContact = primaryContact;
            }
        }

        await RefreshBusinessTypesAsync();
        await GetCompanyPositionsAsync();

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
        </Validation>

If you note I have Test = Input as a test and if I then;
        <Validation Validator="@ValidationRule.None">
            <Field Horizontal="true" ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is6.OnDesktop">
                <FieldLabel ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is3.OnDesktop">Group</FieldLabel>
                <FieldBody ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is9.OnDesktop">
                    <TextEdit @ref="companyGroupTextBox" @bind-Text="@Test.Group" Placeholder="Enter the Company Group Name..">
                    </TextEdit>
                </FieldBody>
            </Field>
        </Validation>

The Test.Group value appears?
For completness in the base class I have tried the following to trigger the chang ein state to update;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _isInitialized = true;
    await ResetAsync();
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        _isInitialized = true;
        await ResetAsync();
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _isInitialized = false;
}

public virtual async Task ResetAsync()
{
    try
    {
        if (InputModelPreSetData != null)
        {
            Input = InputModelPreSetData.DeepCopy();
        }
        else
        {
            Input = new TInput();
        }

        if (!renderHandle.IsInitialized)
        {
            //not intialised so return to avoid an error
            return;
        }

        if (FormValidations == null)
        {
            FormValidations = new Validations();
        }
        else
        {
            await FormValidations.ClearAll();
        }
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error in ResetAsync '{ex.Message}'");
    }
    finally
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

Can anyone tell me why Blazor doesn't seem to be picking up the change in state on the base model parameter please?

Your logic looks a little tangled.
You don't show where Input comes from but you assign it to Test immediately.  You do a bit of assignment and then await three async processes.
Assuming these yield, the component lifecycle logic continues and completes the first render. If the awaits are still incomplete, OnAfterRenderAsync is run for the first time.
I can see from ResetAsync you're resetting Input in this code:
        if (InputModelPreSetData != null)
        {
            Input = InputModelPreSetData.DeepCopy();
        }
        else
        {
            Input = new TInput();
        }

Test and Input now point to different objects, which is where your problem almost certainly lies.
Unfortunately, breakpoints may not provide a true picture here.  You may need to do some console writes to see what's happening in real time.
I'm not offering any revised code: there's not enough code to understand your intent.  However, it's likely the code you currently have in OnAfterRenderAsync belongs in the main lifecycle code i.e. OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}.  OnAfterRenderAsync is a UI event, not an intrinsic part of the component lifecycle.
